# Installing the gsl package on Mac

Tags: r, macos, installation, package, gsl

I’m trying to install the “rtdists” packag. It needs “gsl” but installing was failed. Checking a couple of pages, I first installed gsl generally on terminal, with homebrwe (brew install gsl). But Rstudio still shows the following error. Please help me.

```
> install.packages("rtdists")
also installing the dependency ‘gsl’

Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.1:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.1/PACKAGES'
Packages which are only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘gsl’ ‘rtdists’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel) Yes
installing the source packages ‘gsl’, ‘rtdists’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/gsl_2.1-8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 217997 bytes (212 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 212 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rtdists_0.11-5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 532264 bytes (519 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 519 KB

* installing *source* package ‘gsl’ ...
** package ‘gsl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking for gcc... clang -arch arm64
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
checking whether clang -arch arm64 accepts -g... yes
checking for clang -arch arm64 option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking for gsl-config... /usr/local/bin/gsl-config
checking if GSL version >= 2.5... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c airy.c -o airy.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c bessel.c -o bessel.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c clausen.c -o clausen.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c coulomb.c -o coulomb.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c coupling.c -o coupling.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c dawson.c -o dawson.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c debye.c -o debye.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c dilog.c -o dilog.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c ellint.c -o ellint.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c elljac.c -o elljac.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c error.c -o error.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c expint.c -o expint.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c fermi_dirac.c -o fermi_dirac.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c gamma.c -o gamma.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c gegenbauer.c -o gegenbauer.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c hyperg.c -o hyperg.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c init.c -o init.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c laguerre.c -o laguerre.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c lambert.c -o lambert.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c legendre.c -o legendre.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c log.c -o log.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c poly.c -o poly.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c pow_int.c -o pow_int.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c psi.c -o psi.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c qrng.c -o qrng.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c rng.c -o rng.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c synchrotron.c -o synchrotron.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c transport.c -o transport.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c trig.c -o trig.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c vector.c -o vector.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -I.  -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c zeta.c -o zeta.o
clang -arch arm64 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/opt/R/arm64/lib -o gsl.so airy.o bessel.o clausen.o coulomb.o coupling.o dawson.o debye.o dilog.o ellint.o elljac.o error.o expint.o fermi_dirac.o gamma.o gegenbauer.o hyperg.o init.o laguerre.o lambert.o legendre.o log.o poly.o pow_int.o psi.o qrng.o rng.o synchrotron.o transport.o trig.o vector.o zeta.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/lib/libgsl.dylib, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/lib/libgslcblas.dylib, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/00LOCK-gsl/00new/gsl/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gsl’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/00LOCK-gsl/00new/gsl/libs/gsl.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/00LOCK-gsl/00new/gsl/libs/gsl.so, 0x0006): symbol not found in flat namespace (_gsl_poly_eval)
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/gsl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gsl’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘gsl’ is not available for package ‘rtdists’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/rtdists’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rtdists’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/jh/hzvwkysn7jv9sjg0qcldrdh00000gn/T/RtmpS2Eeeg/downloaded_packages’
```

MacBook Pro 2021

macOS Monterey version 12.6.6

Apple M1 Max

R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) -- "Bird Hippie"

Rstudio version2023.03.1+446 (2023.03.1+446)

Comment: It’s always a good idea to admit that part of your R tool chain was installed by Homebrew. My guess is that you need to learn how to set environment variables and CMD parameters to support the hybrid installation. And that advice is especially relevant if you knowingly intend to run an out-of-date version of R.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I have no knowledge about how to set environment variables and CMD parameters now but will google them.

Comment: I think R 4.1 was released before Macs started having arm CPUs. So you're going to need to get some C programming help from someone smarter than either you or me.